# Chosen dropdown with large data

Tags: jquery, ajax, dropdown, jquery-chosen

I'm using a chosen dropdown, I'm showing data from DB table to the chosen dropdown, which is having almost 90k rows of data. It takes too much time to load data in chosen dropdown & hence it takes too much time to page loading as well.
Can anybody help me to reduce page load time & data loading in a chosen dropdown?

[I'm using this chosen dropdownn](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: you need some server side filtering

Comment: You could Ajax some relevant results based on user input and update the `<option>`, then trigger the `chosen:updated` event. From the [documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) --> `$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");`

Comment: I try this, but its not working, still it takes too much time

Answer (score 0):

The [Select2](https://select2.org/) plugin adds [AJAX support](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) which is what you are looking for. I suggest you jump to using that and server side interaction.

I believe it was a fork of Chosen, that was further developed.